# как передать шрифт в этикетку?

Tags: qt, текст, qfont

Не могу понять почему не могу передать шрифт в этикетку (ака label ) ??

**.h**

```
#include <QFont>

...
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

...
    // подстраиваемый шрифт label
    QFont* font;
    int height_monitor {0};
    int width_monitor  {0};

...

}
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // тут настраиваю и объявляю элементы

    font = new QFont();
    ...
}


void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
      height_monitor= e->size().height();
      width_monitor = e->size().width();

      font->setPointSize((height_monitor*width_monitor)/4);
      
      ui->label->setFont(font);  // вот тут не работает !!!!!
}
```

Comment: Не работает, но собирается?

Comment: У меня этот безобидный с виду пример, во-первых не собирается, во-вторых, будучи исправленным, завершает сеанс под Убунту с потерей всех данных и закрытием запущенных приложений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь несколько ошибок:

- нарушена сигнатура функции `setFont(const QFont &)` - передается указатель;
- значение `(height_monitor*width_monitor)/4` может быть слишком большое;
- в `Qt` нет проверки на слишком большое значение, передаваемое в `setPointSize`, что может привести к краху программы и даже системы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А что делать, то надо?? Что ввести чтоб работало?

Comment: Ну, например, я вместо 4 подставил 40000 - и уже стало лучше. Наверное, нужно ограничить диапазон сверху и снизу, м.б. увеличение размера сделать нелинейным.

Comment: ui->label->setFont(*font) так надо??

Comment: Если Вы об этом, то да, так можно. Либо не в куче, а на стеке определить `QFont font;`. Тем более, что все равно в `h` файле есть подключение к заголовочному файлу `#include <QFont>`. Тогда разыменовывать не нужно. И new тоже излишне.